# How to export Plug-in along with the required dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have successfully created a plug-in. However, this plug-in requires multiple other plug-ins as dependencies. Is it possible that when a user installs the plug-in I made, it will also download the required dependencies into their Eclipse?

Furthermore, how would I know what plug-ins are required? I have them set up in my dependencies but the ones listed are the specific packages. I have a lot of plug-ins installed and I'm quite confused on which ones were required. But so far I know that E4 is one.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add more details? Generally you would do this with a feature project + dependencies and list out the p2 sites that had the dependencies somewhere. How are you building? What happens when user tries to install plug-in now (i.e. which error message do you get)? Keep in mind you have at least two alternatives, one publish dependencies on your p2 site and two publish deps on alternate site/original site.

Comment: Hi @JonahGraham. I'm currently using a Feature + Update Site combo. In the Feature, I compute for the dependencies. Then add that feature into an Update Site. So far, I can't seem to find the place where you input the sites to download the dependencies. When the user tries to install it, it always comes up with an error saying that the required package is missing in their Eclipse.

Comment: Have a look, for example, at how http://www.eclipse.org/ease/ does it to install jython, but there are other ways too.

Comment: Hi @JonahGraham, thank you. I'll check it out!